# Split video with MobileFFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I need to split a video into pieces smaller than 15 seconds using ffmpeg on android.

For this I am using this [library](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) to use FFmpeg and tried to use the code below, but it did not work.

```
    private val destPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/TESTFOLDER"
```

```
    if (video != null) {
        val command =
            "ffmpeg -i $video -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:15 -f segment $destPath output%03d.mp4"

        mProgressDialog.show()

        try {
            val executionId = FFmpeg.executeAsync(command) { _: Long, returnCode: Int ->
                when (returnCode) {
                    RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS -> {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Async command execution completed successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    RETURN_CODE_CANCEL -> {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Async command execution cancelled by user.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Async command execution failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

I tried with `video = /data/user/0/com.vitor238.videoEditor/cache/e4c9d2f3-6127-43fa-a293-e0de614f4993.mp4` and `video = content://media/external/video/media/187130` but neither worked.

Comment: Did ffmpeg execute or did your script fail before it could execute ffmpeg? What are the error messages? Is the problem with your script or ffmpeg?

Comment: @llogan,  the problem was my command. I changed it to "-i $videoPath -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:15 -f segment " + destPath + "output%03d.mp4" and it worked.

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your question since you found solution.